# Electrical switch issue

Tags: wiring

[image]Do you see any issues with this wiring? I have no idea what the middle switch is for. The one on right is 3 way and I assume middle is 3 way, but not sure what it goes to.... All I know is the outlet under these switches doesn't work.

Comment: Switch on the left has too much bare wire showing, and looks like part is burned/melted.

Comment: Only the right switch is 3-way; it has three wires. The others have only two wires so must be standard switches.

Comment: the switch on the left has a melted corner ... someone probably shorted the top screw to the switch box ...  if the bottom wire is the hot wire, then the switch internals may be damaged

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for anyone to know just what the middle switch controls. It could be for "half switched receptacles" which I have in all rooms of my house. In these receptacles, either the top or bottom is controlled by the switch and the other is hot all the time. This is great when using table lamps and etc. You could make sure that the middle switch is working OK, turn it on and test receptacles and lighting sockets with-in the room especially any ceiling light.